# Why did the Mafia respect Jimmy Hoffa so much?

Tags: crime, contemporary-history, john-f-kennedy, organised-crime

The information that I have about **Jimmy Hoffa** has come (the impetus,I must say honestly, came from Scorsese's The Irishman) from [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=11&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwie45X8ppfmAhVGxjgGHZdJA3sQFjAKegQIBhAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.oxygen.com%2Ftrue-crime-buzz%2Fthe-irishman-why-jimmy-hoffa-and-the-mafia-started-fighting&usg=AOvVaw0tiCkua7muEkztEptUi1uB).

**Jimmy Hoffa** was a man with wealth and political connections and his work in Detroit attracted Mafias, well it was **Hoffa's** need too to join hands with Mafias. But as it comes to that wealth of **Hoffa** controlled the Mafias  it seems a little counter-logical with the other facts, like [Lucky Luciano's](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjwi_f1p5fmAhVUzDgGHTyOCQsQFjAAegQIAxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FLucky_Luciano&usg=AOvVaw05GSln5JWVvryCKUKg7nCH) idea of forming **The Commission** was a solely for earning money with the help of *gun*, the setting up of numerous Casinos by Bugsy Siegel and all the investments of Meyer Lansky were the great sources of money, so why Mafias went on respecting **Hoffa**? I have found this *As Attorney General from 1961, Kennedy pursued the strongest attack on organized crime the country had ever seen,[citation needed] and he carried on with a so-called "Get Hoffa" squad of prosecutors and investigators* on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jimmy_Hoffa#Hoffa's_rise_to_power) in the section **Criminal Charges** first paragraph, last two lines. I need a explanation for this, I mean how attack on Hoffa made the Mafia so vulnerable?

**Jimmy Hoffa** was a man who could control the mobs, could order them to kill anyone (someone not protected by the Mafias, for example  Anthony Provenzano, also known as Tony Pro, a capo for the Genovese crime family), it is even suspected that he had his hands in the assassination of **President Kennedy** , why would mobsters follow his orders to go for President only for money (and even they didn't have lack of it)? He used to threaten the **Mafias** and they were afraid of him for too long, he kept them, paid them and made them to do what he wanted just by paying them the money from his Detroit business and sometimes using his political connections to protect them.

So, finally let me restate my question clearly **Why did the Mafias respect Jimmy Hoffa too much when respect is the thing that they wanted all their life?**  This question is equivalent to **What was the relationship between Jimmy Hoffa and the Mafias?** or it is even equivalent to **What was the relationship between the Mafias and the businessmen?**

If the reason is just the money then I request you to please cite some other histories where something like this happened.

Thank you.

EDIT: In the book **I Heard You Paint Houses** Brandt's wrote *“was that if something happened to Bobby, Jack would unleash the dogs. But if something happened to Jack, Vice President Lyndon Johnson would become the president, and it was no secret that Lyndon hated Bobby. Lyndon, it was agreed, definitely would get rid of Bobby as attorney general... Jimmy Hoffa said, ‘Damn right he would. He hates him as much as I do.”*. Doesn't it tell us something?

Comment: Welcome to History:SE.  Perhaps you could edit your question to explain what you think is incorrect about, or missing from, the [Wikipedia article on Jimmy Hoffa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jimmy_Hoffa)?  You might find it helpful to review our [Help Centre](https://history.stackexchange.com/help), and in particular, [ask].

Comment: There are some non-trivial assertions in this question, particularly in the 3rd paragraph, that really need to have references.

Comment: The question also simply asserts that Hoffa was a rich man - the source of his wealth and power is not mentioned.  Hoffa's power did not derive from his wealth but both his power and his wealth derived from his ability to control Labor.  The relationship between Labor and organized crime is complicated.

Comment: @sempaiscuba I have found this _As Attorney General from 1961, Kennedy pursued the strongest attack on organized crime the country had ever seen,[citation needed] and he carried on with a so-called "Get Hoffa" squad of prosecutors and investigators_ on wikipedia in the section **Criminal Charges** first paragraph, last two lines. I need a explanation for this, I mean how attack on Hoffa made the Mafia so vulnerable.

Comment: Unclear: inchoate expression.

Comment: @T.E.D. Yes, those assertions can be quite controversial but [here](https://www.thedailybeast.com/inside-the-irishmans-gonzo-theory-that-the-mob-killed-jfk) in second paragraph it is written that mobs had hands in making Kennedy the President, but the source can't be fully trusted.

Comment: @SamuelRussell What? Can you please elaborate just a little?

Comment: You elaborate excessively: you talk around the point, introduce conspiracy theories, elaborate personal opinion. If there is a question here it can be stated in under a paragraph of question with notes indicating why previous research (for example your reading of the encyclopaedia) leaves an unanswered question.

Comment: @SamuelRussell *Elaborate Personal Opinion* , yeah but they came from the sources that are trusted and they aren't illogical?

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace Well your comment contains information which I was looking for. The complicated relationship, which you have mentioned, can you please write something more on it? or suggest me some resources for that?

Comment: I'm confused by that response. If you don't believe those assertions can be backed up with references, why are they being asserted?

Comment: @T.E.D. I have mentioned the references, all I said was that they could be controversial (although a great number of public have access to those same references).

Comment: @adeshmishra Did you look at the reference cited for that section of the Wikipedia page?  If it helps. archive.org has at least two copies of Kennedy's [The Enemy Within](https://archive.org/details/enemywithin0000kenn).